# While loop not ending when variable is equal to zero

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm making a game where the player deals damage to the enemy to end a battle (like most games).
However, I encountered a problem.

```
while battle != 0:
    playerturn()
    time.sleep(1)
    allyturn()
    time.sleep(1)
    enemyturn()
    time.sleep(1)

print("Battle complete.")
```

The while loop above loops without ending, so the "Battle Complete" never appears.

In `playerturn()` and `allyturn()`, the enemy's HP is reduced. If the enemy's HP is at or below 0 in `enemyturn()`, `battle = 0`.
This is in `enemyturn()`...

```
if eHP <= 0:
    #eHP stands for enemy HP
    print("Bandit Robber is defeated.")
    battle = 0
```

I made sure to import time before, and that's not the problem anyways.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an example code that is basically the same:

```
import random

def testpart():
    battle = 0

def test():
    battle = 1
    while battle != 0:
        print("This is testing.")
        testpart()

test()
```

Comment: I'm also new to Python, so sorry if I did something stupid. If more details are needed I will provide.

Comment: I'm going on some assumptions here since some of the code is missing. Have you declared `battle` outside of the functions?

Comment: [mre]..........

Comment: I've only used the battle variable inside the functions. Is that it?

Comment: @Sameow most likely but please provide a proper example like Manuel linked you.

Comment: So if truly in `enemyturn()` sets `battle = 0` could you humor us and `print(battle)` every iteration to prove it became `0` yet the `while battle:` loop never breaks...

Comment: try this, instead of while battle != 0 try while battle: if battle is 0 this will return false and will not enter while loop.

Comment: @Sameow it's almost definitely that (especially since in Python there is no syntactic distinction between declaring a new variable and updating the value of an existing variable). Also as a small code-style note, if you have a variable that needs a comment to explain what it stands for (`eHP`) consider renaming the variable to one that's easier to understand (`enemy_hp`).

Comment: @RazzleShazl I just tested that, it prints 0.

Comment: Now that you tried printing within your function `enemyturn()`, try printing within your `while battle:` loop.  These are difference scopes, and each has its own `battle` variable.

Comment: Now it's 1. Why is that? @RazzleShazl

Comment: Initially the program execution scope is `main` and all variables are created within this scope.  When the program execution enters a function (in this case, `def enemyturn()`), a new scope is always created.  So, you are only testing main's `battle` but only ever setting enemyturn's `battle`.  See answer by @Silvio.  Using `global` says *do not create a new variable, look for an identical variable in a higher scope, and directly read/write to that variable*.  In this way, you share state between the scopes.

Answer (score 1):

testpart() should return battle value.

```
def testpart():
    battle = 0
    return battle


def test():
    battle =1
    while battle :
        print("This is testing.",battle)
        battle = testpart()
        print(battle)
        


test()
```

Comment: I think this is more of a comment than an answer.  I didn't downvote it but don't see it's purpose here.

Comment: I had already commented,  could not expain it properly through comment so posted answer. Anyway, I have updated my code.

Comment: @sameow, you are missing return for the functions you have defined in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the variable `battle` exists before the function is defined, you can hack this together with a simple `global` declaration.

```
def enemyturn():
    global battle
    ...
```

(You'll need to do this at the top of every function that uses the variable)

However, this is generally considered bad coding practice for lots of reasons. The correct way to resolve a problem like this is to return a Boolean from your function indicating whether the battle should continue and to structure your code procedurally, rather than relying on global mutable state everywhere. The crux of that is much too large to fit into a single StackOverflow answer, but assuming you're following a halfway decent Python tutorial, you'll get to that sort of thing eventually. Just take it slow and one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `battle` variable to the `enemyturn()` function. Then return `battle`. This should make it work the way you want. Currently the battle variable is being changed to 0 within the wrong scope, so it's not detecting it in the main loop.

Comment: Variables in Python are passed by value, so simply passing it as an argument won't modify the existing one in the calling scope.

Comment: if you passed `[battle]` then yeah you could modify the contents of that list (call by object reference) and have the caller see changes.  But if you pass any shallow variables like an `int` then it is by value.  Your suggestion to pass an `int` only works if you also return a value and capture it, e.g. `battle = enemyturn(battle)`